# Increment a unique field with specified character pattern

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to find a way to increment a user defined idenitifer. I have written something that achieves what I want the code to do, but I highly doubt it's the best way to do this:

The character pattern is:

AAA000
AAA999
BAA000
BAA999
BBA000

And so on, although:

AAA000
AAA999
BAA000
BAA999
CAA000

Would be acceptable.

Here is my code to just generate that pattern:

```
int i = 30;

char char1 = 'A';
char char2 = 'A';
char char3 = 'A';
double number = 998;

for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    string id = $"{char1}{char2}{char3}{number.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0')}";

    if (number == 999)
    {
        number = 998;

        if (char1 == char2 && char1 == char3 && char1 != 'Z')
        {
            char1++;
        }
        else if (char1 > char2 && char2 != 'Z')
        {
            char2++;
        }
        else if (char3 != 'Z')
        {
            char3++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        number++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(id);
}
```

To clarify, I need to build a function that can take the latest value, for example:

DEF123
which in turn will return:
DEF124

Or DEF999 which will return DEG000.

Using Maximillians answer, I have amended the method:

```
    static void NextId(string highestId)
    {
        char startChar1 = highestId[0];
        char startChar2 = highestId[1];
        char startChar3 = highestId[2];
        int startNumber = int.Parse(highestId.Substring(highestId.Length - 3));

        int n = 1;
        int i = 0;

        for (char char1 = startChar1; char1 <= 'Z' && i < n; char1++)
        {
            for (char char2 = startChar2; char2 <= 'Z' && i < n; char2++)
            {
                for (char char3 = startChar3; char3 <= 'Z' && i < n; char3++)
                {
                    for (int number = startNumber; number < 1000 && i < n; number++)
                    {
                        string id = $"{char1}{char2}{char3}{number.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0')}";
                        Console.WriteLine(id);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is almost perfect, except:

DEZ998 returns DEZ998, DEZ999 being the highest id passed in returns DEZ999.

Any recommendations on achieving this would be a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do some assumptions on your pattern, but as far as I understood your question I'd use nested loops instead one loop to rule them all.

```cs
int n = 30;
int i = 0;

for (char char1 = 'A'; char1 <= 'Z' && i < n; char1++)
{
    for (char char2 = 'A'; char2 <= 'Z' && i < n; char2++)
    {
        for (char char3 = 'A'; char3 <= 'Z' && i < n; char3++)
        {
            for(int number = 0; number < 1000 && i < n; number++)
            {


                string id = $"{char1}{char2}{char3}{number.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0')}";
                Console.WriteLine(id);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will:

1. Increment the number from `0` to `999`
2. Afterwards it'll increment Char1 by one and start again at (1.) until `Z` is reached
3. Afterwards it'll increment Char2 by one and start again at (2.) until `Z` is reached
4. Afterwards it'll increment Char3 by one and start again at (3.) until `Z` is reached

It will stop at any point if the maximum amount(`n`) is reached

→ You will get a maximum amout of `17575999` possible unique ID's

---

**Update:**

The method `GetNextId(Tuple<char, char, char, int> id)` could help you for that. It calculates the next ID depending on the previous one.

```
void GenerateIDs()
{
    char char1 = 'B';
    char char2 = 'F';
    char char3 = 'A';
    int number = 159;
    int n = 30;

    // this one is the current ID
    var iterationId = new Tuple<char, char, char, int>(char1, char2, char3, number);
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        iterationId = GetNextId(iterationId);
        Console.WriteLine(IdToString(iterationId));
    }
}

/// returns: c1Next, c2Next, c3Next, numberNext
private Tuple<char, char, char, int> GetNextId(Tuple<char, char, char, int> id)
{
    var number = id.Item4 + 1;
    var c3 = id.Item3;
    var c2 = id.Item2;
    var c1 = id.Item1;

    if(number > 999)
    {
        number = 0;
        c3++;
        if(c3 > 'Z')
        {
            c3 = 'A';
            c2++;
            if (c2 > 'Z')
            {
                c2 = 'A';
                c1++;
                if(c1 > 'Z')
                {
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Next ID bigger than \"ZZZ999\"");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return new Tuple<char, char, char, int>(c1, c2, c3, number);
}

private string IdToString(Tuple<char, char, char, int> id)
{
    return $"{id.Item1}{id.Item2}{id.Item3}{id.Item4.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0')}";
}
```

---

**Alternatevly**

You could just store an `int` to the database and use the values `0` to `17575999` and then calculate the display ID

```cs
private string IntToId(int intId)
{
    var number = intId % 1000;
    intId /= 1000;
    char c3 = (char) ('A' + (intId % 26));
    intId /= 26;
    var c2 = (char) ('A' + (intId % 26));
    intId /= 26;
    var c1 = (char) ('A' + (intId % 26));

    return $"{c1}{c2}{c3}{number.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0')}";
}

private int IdToInt(string id)
{
    int c1 = id[0] - 'A';
    int c2 = id[1] - 'A';
    int c3 = id[2] - 'A';
    int number = Int32.Parse(id.Substring(3));
    return ((((((c1 * 26) + c2) *26) + c3) * 1000) + number);
}
```

Comment: My apologies, I will reword the question, while this does achieve what I want, I ideally need to be able to look up the latest value in the DB, for example: DEF123 and return DEF124 or DEF999 and return DEG000